# Recalculating element size on window resize

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, window-resize

How do I propely use `window.addEventListener("resize", () => { })` in the case below, where I need to recalculate `size` on every window resize:

```
const viewportWidth = Math.max(
  document.documentElement.clientWidth,
  window.innerWidth || 0
)

const viewportHeight = Math.max(
  document.documentElement.clientHeight,
  window.innerHeight || 0
)

const elements = list(48, () => {
  const circle = document.createElement("span")
  const minSize = Math.round((viewportWidth + viewportHeight) / 72)
  const maxSize = Math.round((viewportWidth + viewportHeight) / 21)
  const size = random(minSize, maxSize)
  Object.assign(circle.style, {
    width: `${size}px`,
    height: `${size}px`
  })
  return circle
})
```

For whatever reason, I’m struggling with this, and I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: You probably should debounce a resize event handler

Comment: @customcommander Could you please post an example as an answer on how you would do it?

Comment: It's not clear what's your issue. You know the event to listen to and how to attach a listener to it. So what's wrong?

Comment: @Tzar I added a answer. Hope it will work as per your expectation. Please have a look.

Answer (score 2):

**Try this :**

```js
window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
 const docHeight = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight);
  document.getElementById('documentHeight').innerHTML = docHeight;
});
```

```html
<div id="documentHeight">
Open this demo in full page view and resize the window to get the Inner height of the document.
</div>
```

Comment: Your issue is "Recalculating element size on window resize" .. right

Comment: Yes, `const size` which is based on `const minSize` and `const maxSize` should be recalculated on window resize.

Answer (score 1):

You may simply encapsulate the above logic within the callback function within your event listener.

For instance,

```
class yourClass {
  constructor() {
    window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
      // logic to carry out recalculation
      elements();
    });
  }
  // the rest of your logic
}
```

Doing so will ensure that the methods/functions will be called whenever the `resize` event is triggered on the `Window`.

Comment: Could you please post a full solution because I’m a dummy who can’t get this to work? I apologize. Thank you.

Comment: Why do you need to wrap that within a constructor? Each instance of this constructor will add the same listener and perform the same computation. You should at least provide a way to remote the listener.